# why does g++ need both definitions of template class and its friend function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, g++, friend

I want to write a friend function for a template class.
In visual studio, I can ignore the pre-definition both.
But in g++, it is mandatory.
Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// g++ needs, vs do not needs
template <class T>
class A;

template <class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & c, const A<T> & v);
//- end of g++ needs

template <class T>
class A {
    T _v;
public:
    A() {}
    A(T v) : _v(v) {}
    friend ostream & operator<<<T>(ostream & c, const A<T> & v);
};
template <class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & c, const A<T> & v) {
    c << v._v; return c;
}
```

Comment: my best guess is that VisualStudio "helps" you a little more than g++ does, and just adds it for you. Ironically g++ seems to give you better compile error descriptions.  What I mean by "help" is once VS opened `file.txt` when I typed `File.txt` in my code, but g++ said the file was not there and couldn't open.

Comment: In g++, `friend` function declarations (or definitions?) require a prototype. To make the prototype, you in turn need a forward declaration of your template class. Having learnt this once in g++, I was wondering these days that my code worked in VS _without_ (but I didn't dig deeper.) Now, it is clear to me. (Thanks for your question.)

Comment: @BrianW I believe, your mentioned example about `file.txt` vs. `File.txt` is simply an OS issue. On Windows, file names are handled case insensitive in general. (An application may break it if it doesn't use system functions.) On Linux, of course, file names are always case sensitive (but, again, an application may break it if not using system functions). However, in general I agree with you: VS is much more lax (convenient?) about the C++ standard. I always stumble over this when we port our applications to Linux/g++ which we develop in Windows/VS (though we always try to make portable code).

Comment: good point @Scheff, I didn't think about the Windows vs Linux thing and thought it was just the IDE's.

Comment: @YunfeiDuan Please, do not post "Thank you" comments. If you want to say "Thank you", please, up-vote the answer. (This lets the author earn 10 points of reputation and will definitely be welcome.) Please, don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer which you consider as solution of your question (+15 for the author).

Comment: @Scheff Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to vote.That's why I commented "Thank you". Once I've got enough reputation, I will get back and vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
friend ostream & operator<<<T>(ostream & c, const A<T> & v);
```

is a specialization of

```
template <class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & c, const A<T> & v);
```

you need to declare that first and the

```
A<T>
```

part means you have to declare that too before the operator declaration

```
template <class T>
class A;
```

So VS is probably wrong as [C++14](http://timepp.github.io/doc/cpp14/temp.friend.html)

```
14.5.4 Friends [temp.friend]
```

gives the example

```
template<class T> class task;
template<class T> task<T>* preempt(task<T>*);

template<class T> class task {
  friend void next_time();
  friend void process(task<T>*);
  friend task<T>* preempt<T>(task<T>*);
  template<class C> friend int func(C);

  friend class task<int>;
  template<class P> friend class frd;
};
```

Where your example fits the 3rd friend declaration.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC template code is fundamantally broken.  They have been rebuilding it over the last few years, but it still contains quirks like what you are observing.  This is because it was built to be almost macro like, instead of being what the C++ standard required.

In gcc you can do away with the forward declarations by defining the `<<` operator inline in the body of the class:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& c, const A& v){
  c << v._v;
  return c;
}
```

this has the advantage that `<<` becomes no longer a `template`, but rather a distinct non-template created for each  instance of the template `A`.  In some scenarios this tends to work better.