# Modern C++ scope clarification / variable visibility

Tags: c++

While recently migrating older code (with permissive-), I found one small item that I didn't expect.  The derived class could no longer access a protected variable without fully qualifying the name.  Consider this **very contrived** example:

```
// CVTW == contrived value type wrapper
template<typename VALUE_TYPE>
class CVTW
{
public:
    explicit CVTW(VALUE_TYPE const value) : _value { value }
    { }

protected:
    VALUE_TYPE _value;  // <-- target in question
};
// .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
class IntValueType : public CVTW<int>
{
public:
    using CVTW<int>::CVTW;
    int GetValue() const { return _value; } // <-- compiles
};
// .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
template<typename VALUE_TYPE>
class CTVW_2 : public CVTW<VALUE_TYPE>
{
    // another solution to successfully access _value directly
    //using CVTW<VALUE_TYPE>::_value;

public:
    using CVTW<VALUE_TYPE>::CVTW;
    VALUE_TYPE GetValue() const
    {
        //return _value;                 // <-- error
        return CVTW<VALUE_TYPE>::_value; // <-- compiles
    }
};
// .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
int main()
{
    IntValueType v { 1 };
    CTVW_2<int> v2 { 2 };
}
```

When attempting to access `_value` from `CTVW_2` (without fully qualifying the name or a using statement) the following error is reported:

> error: use of undeclared identifier '_value'

I realize this has nothing to do with protected access scope, and I have some understanding of name hiding and the fragile base problem, but in this case, why is this necessary and why is there no error reported when `IntValueType` accesses the same variable in the same manner?

EDIT:
   Here is a working [example](https://godbolt.org/g/mHUvtn).  MSVC isn't as picky, but Clang and GCC report the issue.

Comment: It's a dependent name (more precisely, a name of a member of a dependent base class). You can also say `this->_value`.

Comment: IMHO, this isn't necessarily a C++17 issue (though I'm not sure whether you intended to state this). I realized this even when we were on VS2008 and ported to Linux. (It's probably 4 years ago and I cannot remember what g++ we used then.) IMHO, this happens always when you have template classes derived from something and try to access derived members. As you already told: MSVC is quite lax about certain things.

Comment: @Scheff - I agree, and I didn't mark the question as such. However I noticed older compilers I was using didn't report the issue

Comment: @KerrekSB - Good point.  But why is IntValueType able to access the variable directly?  And why did older compilers not enforce this?

Comment: @Isabelle: Because it's not dependent there, on account of `IntValueType` not being a template.

Comment: This is an old deficiency in VC++ that is about to be fixed https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/

Comment: @BoPersson - nice catch.

Comment: @Scheff - I removed the mention of C++17

Comment: This is a somehow related question from a month ago: [SO: why does g++ need both definitions of template class and its friend function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46986853/7478597).

Comment: @BoPersson is right.  This is a two-phase name lookup question, and answered well by Steve Jessop.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer/4643295#4643295